# Qt (PySide) multiline QSyntaxHighlighter

Tags: qt, multiline, qtextdocument

I need a `QTextEdit` that will feed my `QSyntaxHilighter` **multiline** blocks! I've narrowed down my search in to the `QAbstractTextDocumentLayout` but I can't really nail it. The documentation states:

> A text block encapsulates a block or **paragraph** of text in a `[...].QTextDocument`.

Regardless of that, I can't find anything to set or override so I can get the required behavior. Can somebody point me to the right direction please? I'm oozing my brain out of my ears here!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution i found was to subclass the `QtGui.QTextCursor` state the patterns for the regular expressions i needed as in the `QSyntaxHighlighter` and use `setCharFormat()` on my selections.. (while blocking the signals).